# What happens if I do not delete a dynamically created variable?

Tags: c++, new-operator

I am a beginner in C++.I was wondering what will happen if I do not delete memory
allocated using new operator.Why is it considered a bad practice?I have heard that even if I do not free dynamically allocated memory the OS will free it sooner or later.Can this practice crash the application or cause any bugs or is
it just discouraged?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int* arr = new int[10];
   
   arr = new int[5];//initializing again with new
}
```

Comment: 1) Such code creates a memory leak, since nothing releases the memory allocated by `new int[10]`. 2) "_initializing again_" You cannot initialize twice. `arr = new int[5]` is an assignment.

Comment: Doing so would leak memory. That's not a question of _"bad practice"_, but a no go.

Comment: You can only initialise a variable once.

Comment: Except in special cases, Yes/No questions are almost never a good fit for StackOverflow as you'll get exactly the kind of answer you see below: a simple Yes or No. Are you wondering *why* it's bad practice and you should delete the array? Is there some reason you suspect this is not a good idea? These are details that could make this a more interesting and better question.

Comment: Expanding on Neil's comment, because it becomes an important distinction later, you can only initialize when you define the variable. `int* arr = new int[10];` is initialization. `arr = new int[5];` is an assignment.

Comment: Sidenote: prefer `std::vector<int> arr(10);` to `int* arr = new int[10];` where possible. `vector` is self-maintaining and self deleting. It can also resize the array as you fill it, which you'll find to be very handy. [Documentation for `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely a memory leak and a very very very bad practice.

First, you don't want to take system resource like memory, abandon it but not release it.

Second, your code works because you are only creating memory leak of 10 integers. If it was a commercial application and this bug was in code or many parts of the code and it gets executed over and over, it could cause a nasty un-deterministic crashes.

You can simulate this by wrapping your code in large loop like 10k iterations. Try it without deleting the memory and than with deleting it. You will see the difference. The one without deleting will crash at some point when the memory is exhausted.

Comment: Or if you are certain big corporations and don't want to fix the bug you can simply re-start the processes every couple of hours to get around the leak. :-)